# Alfred workflow launch apps, Dispatch key combo, how to type in input text?

Tags: workflow, alfred

When develop alfred workflow, I

> keyword -> Launch Apps/Files -> Key Combo -> **how pass the {query} to textfield(input box) of app** ?

I set key Combo `CTRL+F` , means launch communication app and `Key Combo` find somebody,
My problem is how to pass the output text(from keyword) to the textfield(input box) of app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know you should use 'Copy to Clipboard' tool and choose 'Automatically paste to frontmost app' in configuration. Also you might want to check 'Mark item as transient in clipboard' option if you don't want to save the text to clipboard.